# Detect network connectivity without subscription

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

As described in the [Cordova Network Information Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information), we must subscribe to *online* and *offline* events to detect the network connectivity status.

Is there a way to know what is the network status without listening to these events?

**Example**:
Before performing an action from my mobile app, I need to know if there is a network connectivity: If there is a connection I perform my action, otherwise I display a message that indicates to the user that he must be online.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Network` type, there is the `type` attribute that contains the value `none` if the network is offline.

This is an example of a service that checks the offline status of the network:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Network, Connection } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NetworkService {

  constructor(private network: Network) {}

  public isOffline() {
    return this.network.type.toLowerCase() == Connection[Connection.NONE].toLowerCase();
  }
}
```